# Error when trying to change play button in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm trying to use a play button image that changes to a pause image when clicked on and resets to the play icon if a stop button is pressed, but even though I'm following examples I'm getting error messages - use of unresolved identifier image. Some of the code is below:

```
@IBOutlet var playButtonText: UIButton!

@IBAction func playPauseButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    var playBtn = sender as! UIButton
    if (audioPlayer.isPlaying==true){
        audioPlayer.stop()

        playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        audioPlayer.play()
        playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)

    }
}


@IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: Any) {
    audioPlayer.stop()
   `playButtonText.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)`      
}
```

I've tried ending with 'for: .normal' and also referring to the image in the assets folder, but still am getting errors - I'd really appreciate help please

Comment: What and where is the error you are seeing? Add as much information as you can so others can help you.

Comment: do play.png and pause.png exist in you assets?

Comment: What version of Xcode/Swift are you using?

Comment: Do you forget to connect the IBOutlet button to the xib/storyboard?

Comment: Thanks for your help - for some reason when I deleted it and rewrote it again there was no error - not sure what was going on!